# Java - Making multiple requests using HTTP2

Tags: java, http2, java-11

I have not been able to find any great examples to outline using `Java`'s new `HTTP2` support.

In previous versions of Java (`Java 8`) I was making many calls to a `REST` server using multiple threads.

I had a global list of parameters and I would go through the parameters to make different sorts of requests.

For example:

```
String[] params = {"param1","param2","param3" ..... "paramSomeBigNumber"};

for (int i = 0 ; i < params.length ; i++){

   String targetURL= "http://ohellothere.notarealdomain.commmmm?a=" + params[i];

   HttpURLConnection connection = null;

   URL url = new URL(targetURL);
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

   //Send request
   DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
        connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.close();

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

//Do some stuff with this specific http response

}
```

In the previous code what I would do is construct multiple `HTTP` requests to the same server with just a little change in the parameter. This took a while to complete so I even would break up the work using threads so that each thread would work on some chunk of the param array.

With `HTTP2` I would now not have to create a brand new connection every time. The problem is I do not quite understand how to implement this using the new versions of Java (`Java 9 - 11`).

If I have an array param as I do previously how would I do the following:

```
1) Re-use the same connection?
2) Allow different threads to use the same connection?
```

Essentially I am looking for an example to do what I was doing previously but now utilizing `HTTP2`.

Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This took a while to complete so I even would break up the work using threads so that each thread would work on some chunk of the param array.

With Java 11's `HttpClient`, this is actually very simple to achieve; all you need is the following snippet:

```
var client = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2).build();

String[] params = {"param1", "param2", "param3", "paramSomeBigNumber"};

for (var param : params) {
    var targetURL = "http://ohellothere.notarealdomain.commmmm?a=" + param;
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(new URI(targetURL)).build();
    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
          .whenComplete((response, exception) -> {
              // Handle response/exception here
          });
}
```

This uses HTTP/2 to send the request asynchronously and then handles the response `String` (or `Throwable`) when it is received in a callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried to run it and it runs but nothing seems to happen. Inside of the "whenComplete" method I added               System.out.println(response.statusCode()) and             System.out.println(exception.getMessage()); to see what is being returned, but nothing prints out?. I tried using another url: var targetURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" and nothign as well.

Comment: The requests are sent asynchronously, and I suspect that your program is exiting before the response is received (since the main thread terminates). To fix this, you can use a custom `ExecutorService` and block the main thread until the responses are received, or change the code to use `send` instead, which is blocking and does not use multiple threads.